# Change font size of \texttt globally?

Tags: fontsize, typewriter

I'm using [TeX Gyre Pagella](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/tgpagella/) as the main font of a document which is typeset using a font size of 10pt. For the technical terms, I want to replace the default Computer Modern Typewriter with [Bera Mono](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/beramono/) -- mostly because of the dotted zero. The problem is that now the terms marked with `\texttt{}` appear too large compared to the rest of the text.

```
\documentclass[pdftex,fontsize=10pt]{scrbook}

\usepackage{tgpagella}        
\usepackage[scaled]{beramono} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}      

\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis non velit in ligula volutpat
condimentum. Now for some technical terms: \texttt{Phasellus}, \texttt{ultrices} aliquam
\texttt{nulla}, in imperdiet magna feugiat sed. Ugh, the technical terms are too large             
compared to the rest of the text. 
\end{document}
```

How can I tell (pdf)LaTeX to use a smaller font size (9pt?) for the `\texttt{}` parts only?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

default value for option 'scaled'  is '.9. You can set scale to explicit value, e.g.,
`\usepackage[scaled=.7]{beramono}`

Comment: excellent! Probably needs to be tweaked on a font-by-font basis. In my case, ``scaled=0.85`` was best, judged by comparing the height of the letter ``a``.