# Change font style for \texttt

Tags: fonts, listings, code

I am afraid if this is a repeat question. I have checked the following links for any hints:

[Change font size of \texttt globally?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/81743/change-font-size-of-texttt-globally)

[Using same font for \texttt and \Verb](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/101680/using-same-font-for-texttt-and-verb)

The question is simply. I want to change the font style for `\texttt`. The bigger problem is I am unsure of the 'exact' font I want but it's one of the popular fonts used for code listings. It's probably similar to Palatino but I am not sure about it.

Comment: May be the question is simple, but too vague also. See [The LaTeX font Catalogue, section typewriter fonts](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/typewriterfonts.html).