# How to change the \texttt font

Tags: typewriter

[This](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/140675/change-font-style-for-texttt) question is the most similar to my own, but it was closed before anyone could answer it. Looking [here](https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/typewriterfonts.html) there are quite a few "Typewrite" fonts built into LaTeX. I was wondering what the default font is for `\texttt`, and how I would go about changing the font to one of the others on this list.

Comment: The answers depend on which system are you using: plainTeX? LaTeX? ConTeXt? and also on which engine do you use to compile: pdf(la)tex? xe(la)tex? lua(la)tex? We cannot answer without a MWE providing those informations.

Comment: I'm using LaTeX and I have no idea which engine is compiling. I'm just using the defaults for a document in TeXShop (on Mac)

Comment: You are probably using pdftex. You can check it in TeXShop compilation options (I don't use TeXShop so don't know where it is).

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you can just use the package, for example:

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tgcursor}
```

You can also use (assuming the font is available):

```
\renewcommand*{\ttdefault}{(font name)}
```

With fontspec, you can also use:

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmonofont{⟨font name⟩}[⟨font features⟩]
```